# Revalidating JTree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtree

I have JTree set up so that, when a user clicks a leaf, then the text for that leaf is displayed in bold. The problem is that, when the text goes to bold, it becomes longer and ends up appearing as
"wh..." instead of "whatever". The solution might be to call revalidate(), but that method is overridden to a do-nothing for DefaultTreeCellRenderer. I can't override this method myself and put back the call to revalidate() since Java doesn't allow super.super.revalidate().

Here's where the bolding/unbolding occurs:

```
class LeafInfo {
  String name; 
  boolean bold = false;
  
  public LeafInfo(String s) {
    this.name = s;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}

class BoldableCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
  
  public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree,Object value,
      boolean sel,boolean expanded,boolean leaf,int row,boolean hasFocus) {
    
    super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree,value,sel,expanded,leaf,row,hasFocus);
    
    // So that the head is never bold.
    Font f = this.getFont();
    this.setFont(f.deriveFont(f.getStyle() & ~ Font.BOLD));
    
    if (leaf == false)
      return this;
    
    DefaultMutableTreeNode n = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
    LeafInfo li = (LeafInfo) n.getUserObject();
    
    if (li.bold == true)
      this.setFont(f.deriveFont(f.getStyle() | Font.BOLD));
    else
      this.setFont(f.deriveFont(f.getStyle() & ~ Font.BOLD));
    
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: You wrote in your question: _The solution might be to call `revalidate()`_ Are you sure? I don't think so because the `JLabel` used to render the text of the `JTree` node, like any `JLabel`, will show the start of the text, followed by an ellipsis, whenever the width of the text is larger than the width of the `JLabel`. Do you think that calling `revalidate()` will change the width of the `JLabel` and make it wide enough to display the entire text?

Comment: As you say, the ellipsis appears because the text is too long to fit in the area dedicated. The question is how to allocate more space, and revalidate() (or something similar) is on the right track. The point is that the layout needs to be redone.

Comment: I don't use a JTree much so I don't know how the size is determined. What happens if the default Font is Bold and then you turn off the Font if the node is not selected? I would use the "sel" value of your method to determine which Font to use.

Comment: Here's a suggestion. Rather than extend `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`, write your own. Copy the code from `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` to your class and change where appropriate.

Comment: Y, considered that, and it may be what I end up doing

Comment: camickr, you're right that there will be enough space if everything starts off as bold, but this requires that the bold text actually be displayed. It appears that the layout doesn't occur until things are actually displayed the first time, and the text should be non-bold when it first appears.

Comment: Well that is not exactly what I suggested. I suggest that you set the Font for the JTree to be bold. Then in the renderer you check if the "sel" value is false and then set the Font to normal. Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem. Maybe somebody will be able to help (likely not me)  if they see the exact problem.